# how to have the logo only on the first page

Tags: fancyhdr

I'm trying to make my personal code for a report template. I would have the logo of the company only in the first page and maintain the header and footer in the rest of the document.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{pbox}  
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=2cm,bottom=2.5cm,left=2.01cm,rigt=2.1cm,bindingoffset=0mm]{geometry}

\usepackage{latexsym} 
\usepackage{framed} 
\setlength\headheight{33pt} %% just to make warning go away. Adjust the value after looking into the warning.
\usepackage{fancyhdr, lastpage}

\fancyhf{} 


\lhead{\includegraphics[scale=1]{logo.PNG}}
\chead{}
\rhead{\footnotesize\bfseries{\pbox[b]{\textwidth}{\color{gray}xxx\\ xxx}}}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt} 
\renewcommand{\headrule}{\hbox 
   to\headwidth{\color{red}\leaders\hrule 
   height\headrulewidth\hfill}} 



   \rfoot{\thepage} 
   \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
 \renewcommand{\footrule}{\hbox 
   to\headwidth{\color{red}\leaders\hrule height 
    \footrulewidth\hfill}}

  \pagestyle{plain}
```

I can't understand where I'm wrong. Please help me!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please -- as usual here -- make your given code snippet compilable. Then we can simply copy your code and test it on our own computer. As it stands now we have to guess what you are doing ...

Comment: I shared it in the brackets. It is not visible?

Comment: You missunderstood me: the given code is not complete, for example `\begin{document}` is missing. To be able to test what you are doing with guessing we need an complete, **compilable** TeX code, called MWE (minimal working example) ...

Answer (score 1):

For a single page, I use tikzpagenodes.  Actually, I avoid fancyhdr as much as possible.  It has some nasty habits.

Remember to run this twice.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}% why do people use XeLaTeX fonts in MWEs?
\usepackage{pbox}  
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=2cm,bottom=2.5cm,left=2.01cm,right=2.1cm,bindingoffset=0mm,headsep=10pt]{geometry}

\usepackage{latexsym} 
\usepackage{framed} 
\usepackage{lastpage}

\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usepackage{lipsum}% MWE only

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
  \node[above right, inner sep=0pt] at (current page header area.south west)
    {\includegraphics[height=33pt]{example-image}};
  \node[above left, inner sep=0pt] at (current page header area.south east)
    {\footnotesize\bfseries{\pbox[b]{\textwidth}{\color{gray}xxx\\ xxx}}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```